# In Rails 3 is it possible or proper to call @variable from another model in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here I met a problem...
I am building a homepage of a website and trying to integrate infos about users, messages, location_infos bla bla bla into the same page (using jquery and ajax)...

In PHP or JSP, I think such page is quite easy to make(divide all these functions into different services and build a homepage to load them), but in Rails 3, I found that actually I could only render @user to the view if the model is 'User' and only @user_group if the model is 'User_group'...

Well, I use 'has_many, belongs_to,has_one' to organize some of these models. (so that I could use variables like user.user_groups.each) But actually there are always something quite different that I think it is not proper to claim these two models had a connection, for example between locations and users...So in this circumstance, how could I refer variables from other models in a certain view page? Or is this quite harmful which I really have to avoid so that I may not seriously break the RESTFul style of pages?

Well here is my codes:

```
Class UsersController< ApplicationController
def home
  if session[:current_user_id]==nil
    redirect_to :action=> "login"
  else
      @user =User.find(session[:current_user_id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render json: @user}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so in the users/home.html.erb

### I could use codes like `@user.XXX` to generate the content

But if I rewrite the method as below:

```
  def home
    if session[:current_user_id]==nil
      redirect_to :action=> "login"
    else

      #here \\\
      @user_2=User.find(session[:current_user_id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render json: @user}
      end
    end
  end
```

I found it impossible to call @user_2 in the users/home.html.erb

And if I add more into the UsersController as:

@user_group=User_group.find(session[:current_user_id])

I found I cannot just render the `@user_group` like `format.html {render @user_group}`
  And I also cannot get the `@user_group` in the users/home.html.erb

Comment: Your question  is a bit hard to understand. Could you show your view and controller code?

Comment: I'm also a little confused - you could try putting your variables in the application controller in a before_filter? That way they will be applied to all controllers and every action. However there's probably a better way to solve your problem if you post your code.

Comment: yeah, you could probably try out the Jamsi version, it'd work

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand what you're asking but I think it might be that you're wanting to send more than just @user to the view. You'd like to send @user_group, @user_location, etc. Is that correct? If that's the case then you don't have to have a render as 'format' statement to use your model variables in your views, just define them like you are.

If this is a question about getting a relation you can get those like User.locations or User.groups. Those will return the list of your users locations and groups (respectively) if your models are set up correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I wanna send things like @user_group to the views without setting up a relation. But if I directly define at user_group or at user_location in the User's controller, I think I cannot just call them in the views. They won't be recognized. I will get error messages like :  LoadError in UsersController#show

Expected F:/rec2/app/models/user_group.rb to define User_group